# PHPMailer connection Failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using digital ocean.

I've been digging to fix this error.

```
2016-10-26 04:35:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ht5sm340860pad.16 - gsmtp
2016-10-26 04:35:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com 2016-10-26 04:35:35  SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [128.199.201.169] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
2016-10-26 04:35:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-10-26 04:35:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2016-10-26 04:35:35 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2016-10-26 04:35:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-10-26 04:35:36 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2016-10-26 04:35:36 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
2016-10-26 04:35:36 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
There was an error! Try again
```

Here is my setting:

```
require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                           

$mail->isSMTP(); 

// Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;              // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'psw';             // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';           // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                   // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('d@gmail.com', 'd');
$mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com', '');     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);                         // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = " Account Confirmation";
$mail->Body    = "Hello. test     Thank you for you using our service! To activate your account, please access this link:\n <a href='http://w2heaven.com/index.php?confirmcode=$confirmcode'>Click here</a> \n";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "There was an error! Try again";
} else {
    echo "Please confirm your email at: blablah";
}
```

More info: It works without gethostbyname(); but extremely slow because DigitalOcean blocks IPv6

Comment: Have you considered following the link to the troubleshooting guide and doing what it says? It looks like you have a TLS problem.

Comment: @Synchro: I tried everything :(

Comment: @Synchro: It works without gethostbyname(); but extremely slow because DigitalOcean blocks IPv6 :(

Comment: OK, so post the results of all the tests in the guide. It will be failing for a reason, and the tests will tell you what that reason is.

Comment: Is using TLS important to you or the project? Or could you do without? For example just non-encrypted SMTP.

Comment: @Synchro: gethostbyname is one of the solution in the troublehooting to get around Digital Ocean IPv6 limits.

Comment: @Brayn: I'm using gmail smtp so i guess tls is important? Do you have any alternative?

Comment: I know that, but it does not address your problem and you have not done what I suggested - **find out why your TLS connection is failing**. It will be that you're missing openssl in PHP, that your certificate doesn't match etc. Telling what that problem is is covered in the guide.

Comment: @Synchro: my opensll is enabled. I've checked that. Also check certificate as well

Comment: So post the tests and results. It's not failing just to annoy you, and it's not a code problem.

Comment: @Synchro: And again it's weird cause it works with $host = "smtp.gmail.com" ( but take a while to send the email though )